# Is it possible to write a grep statement on multiple lines?

Tags: grep

I'd like to improve the readability of a script by writting 1 pattern per line.

Is there a syntax that would allow me to transform `grep 'foo\|bar\|barz'` to something like the following?

```
grep 'foo\|
      bar\|
      barz'
```

Comment: you can also write the terms one per line in a file and use `-f` option

Comment: In any case note that `\|` is a non-standard GNU extension. `grep -E 'foo|bar|barz'` would be standard.

Comment: Isn't it just a flavor of regular expression ? From grep manual: "In  basic  regular  expressions  the  meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions \?, \+, \{, \|, \(, and \).". Though I think I prefer extended regular expressions

Comment: @Sumak, that would be the manual of GNU `grep`. Again `\|` is a GNU extension. [POSIX BREs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) have no `\|`, `\?`... They have `\{`, `\}` which were added to BREs before `{`, `}` were added to ERE (some tools still don't support `{`, `}` in EREs as introducing them breaks backward compatibility).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't see a need for `|` there. You could use multiple `-e` options spread across lines:

```
grep -e foo \
     -e bar \
     -e barz
```

Answer (score 14):

The pattern argument is actually a list of patterns, separated by newlines. This is true even for `grep -F`: you can search for multiple strings. So you can write:

```
grep 'foo
bar
barz'
```

But note that the continuation lines must not be indented: any leading space would be part of the pattern. For this reason, you may prefer to pass the pattern list as separate arguments, with `-e` in front of each pattern. Then you can use `\` at the end of a line to split the shell command across lines between the arguments of the `grep` command. The two syntaxes are equivalent.

```
grep -e 'foo' \
     -e 'bar' \
     -e 'barz'
```

Note that neither of those work with current versions of GNU `grep` when passed the `-P` option (for PCRE regexps) which in those cases fails with `grep: the -P option only supports a single pattern`. You can however use `pcregrep` instead of GNU `grep -P` and use the `x` flag to enter multi-line regexps:

```
pcregrep '(?x)
  foo |
  bar |
  barz'
```

With `(?x)`, all whitespace characters including SPC and NL are ignored allowing you to indent the code as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, indeed I was indenting each lines with leading spaces. `-e` and `\` is exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 2):

**using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
$ cat foo_bar_barz.txt | raku -ne '.grep(/
| foo
| bar
| barz
/).put;'
```

#outputs:

```
1. foo
2. bar
3. barz
```

One of the major reasons for the Perl6 (now Raku) project was to rewrite the regex engine so that more readable code could be inputted. The Raku defaults include the ability to insert spaces between tokens, to write regexes on multiple lines, and also a revision of the "modifier" system (now called "adverbs"). [As an example of the latter, where you used to tag a "g" onto the end of a regex, now that ":g" appears at the head of the regex so you know what you're trying to match from the get-go].

Above is a Raku solution for the example you posted. Note in Raku the `|` alternation operator implements the longest-token-matching (LTM) strategy. Also you can feel free to insert a "leading" `|` alternation operator to help you line up tokens (see above). Raku accepts this as normal.

Below, to give you an idea of what's going on behind the scenes, I capture the three tokens individually using the `m//` match operator instead of `grep()`. Captures are accomplished with parentheses, with numbering beginning from `$0` :

```
$ cat foo_bar_barz.txt | raku -ne 'say  m/
| (foo)
| (bar)
| (barz)
/;'
```

#outputs:

```
｢foo｣
 0 => ｢foo｣
｢bar｣
 0 => ｢bar｣
｢barz｣
 0 => ｢barz｣
Nil
```

Note the input file is as below (with a bogus line at the end to keep me honest):

```
$ cat foo_bar_barz.txt
1. foo
2. bar
3. barz
4. ziggy
```

https://raku.org/